# How to test multi-user feature of 4.2 JellyBean on Nexus 7 tablet emulator?

Tags: nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, android-emulator, multi-user

I know multi-user functionality is available in Android 4.2 JellyBean:

I have gone through [THIS](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#42-multiuser) and [THIS](http://www.android.com/whatsnew/).

But I want to test this feature on my emulator and not on the actual device.

**My Questions:**

1. Is it possible to test multi-user feature on an emulator?
2. If yes, how it can be?

Comment: Highly dubious that this is possible at the moment right now, best to wait and see what Google does, perhaps in the next release of their SDK, there will be an emulator by then, wait and see....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Android emulator doesn't currently support this, unfortunately. There is a configuration file in the build system that determines whether or not to enable the user accounts feature, and it is disabled in the emulator images distributed by Google. You can [star this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40325) on the bug tracker in the meantime.

However there are two alternatives you can look at:

1. You can alter the configuration file and build a new emulator image from the AOSP source and use that in place of the system image that the AVD uses by default. The file in question is in `/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml` within the Android source. There should be an option named `config_multiuserMaximumUsers` which needs to be set to a value greater than 1.
2. You can try the [Jar of Beans](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1975675) emulator package. It has experimental support for multiple user accounts. Note, however, that this is an x86 emulator, not an ARM one.

Comment: Thanks for your Support. but i could not able to find the "/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml" path in my ubantu 11.10 could you help me?

Comment: @Bhavesh: Do you have all of the source code synced to your computer? What steps did you use to set it up?

Comment: which source code i should have for it? could you please give me link for it?

Comment: @Bhavesh: You need the full Android source. It's pretty large, but the instructions for setting it up start here if you'd like to try it: http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html